# BeautifulSoup: scrape HTML only accessible after clicking "Accept" in the same URL

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape some information from a certain URL. Let's call it: `www.foo.bar/baz`

When you access that URL with a web browser, the usual "I'm older than 18" button appears. The URL doesn't change and the real content is only loaded when you manually click said button.

I would like to "simulate" that click in the "I'm older than 18" button in order to be able to access the information that I really want to scrape.

This is the HTML code of the button that should be clicked:

```
<div align=center>
    <a href="javascript:showContent()"><span>ENTRAR</span></a>
</div>
```

And this is the JavaScript function that gets called by the href attribute:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
function showContent() {
    document.getElementById('all-content').style.display = '';
    document.getElementById('adultmessage').style.display = 'none';
    document.cookie = 'adult=yes; path=/';
}
function hideAdultContent(){
    document.getElementById('all-content').style.display = 'none';
}
// --></script>
```

I would appreciate any tips on what to research in order to do this.

Comment: can you share the link?

Comment: @Xar, like Padraic said.  Selenium is your best bet.  Check out the [slack](https://github.com/Wykleph/Slack) framework, as it might help you keep things organized.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham the url is http://www.pasion.com/amistad/ Your have to click on "Entrar" to access the real content.

Comment: @Xar, if you right click and look at the source you see you actually get it, the button is only relevant when you visit the page in a browser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot interact with Javascript using Beautifulsoup, you can use selenium to click the element using it with [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) for headless browsing:

```
from selenium import webdriver

dr = webdriver.PhantomJS()

dr.get("www.foo.bar/baz")

dr.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='javascript:showContent()']").click()
```

The xpath will find the element, then we simulate a click which should give you what you need.

The site I presume is in Spanish so the href is actually `javascript:muestradulto()`:

```
dr.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='javascript:muestradulto()']").click()
```

Once the link is clicked and you `print(dr.page_source)`, you will see you get to the next page which has `EL BUSCANUNCIOS` near the top:

```
In [1]: url = "http://www.pasion.com/amistad/"

In [2]: from selenium import webdriver

In [3]: dr = webdriver.PhantomJS()

In [4]: dr.get(url)

In [5]: dr.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='javascript:muestradulto()']").click()

In [6]: print("EL BUSCANUNCIOS" in dr.page_source)
True
```

If you prefer to use bs4 you can pass the source to BeautifulSoup and work away on that but selenium lets you use xpath and a much larger range of css selectors which you might find more useful.

Actually if you look at what the page returns, you actually get the source code just using requests, the link only needs to be clicked on the webpage:

```
In [14]: from requests import get

In [14]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [15]: soup = BeautifulSoup(get(url).content)

In [16]: print(soup.select("#cuerpo div[class^=x]")[:2])
[<div class="x1"><div class="x2">\n<div class="x3"></div>\n<div class="x4">Amistad en Barcelona  i  rodalies  (BARCELONA)</div>\n<div class="x5">r508491244 </div>\n<div class="x6" style="font-size:8px"><a href="/creditos/auto-renueva.php" style="color:#ee0000">AUTO\xb7RENUEVA</a></div>\n</div>\n<div class="x9"><a class="cti" href="para-mujer-busque-amistad-508491244.htm" target="_blank">PARA MUJER BUSQUE AMISTAD</a><br/><div class="tx"> Deseo coincidir con una mujer que busque una relaci\xf3n de amistad continuada con un hombre maduro,  tranquilo,  educado,  cari\xf1oso y de trato f\xe1cil.  No tengo pareja y ahora no la busco.  Busco una amiga para pasear,  hablar,  echar unas risas,  caf\xe9s,  cines,  conciertos,  etc.  No me importa para nada la talla de suje ni de pantal\xf3n que usas,  ni tu edad,  ni tampoco si tienes eso que ahora se llaman cargas.  Soy un tipo normal y busco lo mismo.  Si necesitas algo m\xe1s,  tambi\xe9n lo podemos hablar.  Con afecto.  Dani. Edad 54 a\xf1os</div><br/> <div class="x11">\n</div>\n</div>\n<div class="x10" id="ph508491244" style="width: auto">\n</div></div>, <div class="x2">\n<div class="x3"></div>\n<div class="x4">Amistad en Barcelona  i  rodalies  (BARCELONA)</div>\n<div class="x5">r508491244 </div>\n<div class="x6" style="font-size:8px"><a href="/creditos/auto-renueva.php" style="color:#ee0000">AUTO\xb7RENUEVA</a></div>\n</div>]
```

So you don't actually need to worry about clicking anything.

Comment: Thank you Padraic! Great explanation! Just one more small question: where do you get the `get` method from? What do I have to import? In your line 15 I'm getting the `NameError: name 'get' is not defined` error message.

Comment: Sorry, meant to copy paste that in, there should have been a `from requests import get`