# Clicking on dynamically loaded menu with python phantomjs

Tags: python, html, selenium, phantomjs

I want to get the transcript from the youtube video below (I know that there is a way to get the cc captions if available, but often they are not).

I use `phantomjs` to do this in python.

```
url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wOn8xawC-HQ'

phantom_driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path="./phantomjs-2.1.1- macosx/bin/phantomjs")

phantom_driver.get(url)
```

The transcript only appears after clicking on the "More ..." button which I can access with:

```
phantom_driver.find_element_by_id('action-panel-overflow-button').click()
```

... this creates a `div` with the compound class `"yt-uix-menu-content yt-ui-menu-content yt-uix-kbd-nav yt-uix-menu-content-hidden"` which contains a menu with a `<ul>` consisting of 4 elements in it.

I need to click on one of these four elements to open the transcript box (specifically, I need to click the button with the compound class `"yt-ui-menu-item has-icon yt-uix-menu-close-on-select action-panel-trigger action-panel-trigger-transcript"`).

However, running

```
phantom_driver.find_element_by_class_name('action-panel-trigger-transcript').click()
```

does not work since the element seems still hidden (`Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated`).

I believe what I need is clicking on the "More..." button and then directly clicking on the opened menu.

I've looked into [this post](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1355/what-is-the-correct-way-to-select-an-option-using-seleniums-python-webdriver) on select menues and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36704329/beautifulsoup-scrape-html-only-accessible-after-clicking-accept-in-the-same-u) on using the html after the click. Neither did quite solve my problem.

What am I missing in my script? Do I need to "refresh" the retrieved html after the click?

Answer (score 0):

"action-panel-overflow-button" is button id not name.
you can click this element by it's xpath

this works fine:

```
phantom_driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="action-panel-overflow-button"]').click()
phantom_driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="yt-ui-menu-item has-icon yt-uix-menu-close-on-select action-panel-trigger action-panel-trigger-transcript"]').click()
```